# .gitignore isn't ignoring my files

Tags: git, phpstorm, bitbucket, gitignore, gitkraken

I'm currently using BitBucket for my repos with the git engine. I'm not using github since is a private project, so I can't set it public.

When I create my `.gitignore` file with gitignore.io, trying to ignore PhpStorm and WebStorm, Gitkraken (which is my git client on Mac) it isn't ignoring the `.idea` folder. And each time I change my workspace layout opening or closing a sidebar or a file, then git is tracking that change. I can't figure out what's wrong, since I've also tried to set `.idea/` in `.gitignore`, but the files inside it are still tracked...

Any ideas?

Comment: Has .idea already been tracked? If yes, .gitignore can not ignore it any more unless you remove it from git repo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/783119 ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @LazyOne, and for the link to the question. I didn't knew that once a file is tracked it can't be ignore unless you remove it from the cache. Thank you all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update your `.gitignore` file. For instance, add one more folder for those you want to untrack in `.gitignore`: `foldername`.

To stop tracking a file, you need to remove it from the index. This can be achieved with the below command.

Remove all tracked files, including wanted and unwanted:

```
git rm --cached .
```

then

All files will be added to track, excluding those in `.gitignore`:

```
git add .
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still new to git :D I really appreciate it!

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Had to use `git rm --cached -r .`

Answer (score 3):

## Solved

How @ElplieKay said, the file once is tracked it can't be ignored anymore. Unless you remove it from git.

Another solution is to remove the file or folder (using -r) from the shell. So on the next commit it will be ignored.

Comment: You could ignore the files that already tracked by simply `git update-index –assume-unchanged /path/to/file`.